# how to push certain files to repository

Tags: git

I have a file in folder/anotherFolder/file.php

I want to add, commit and push, 
what is the process can someone show me a sample command for pushing file.php to a remote repository?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ git add folder/anotherFolder/file.php
$ git commit [-m'your message here']
$ git push
```

or, if there are no working copy changes you *don't* want to commit, just:

```
$ git commit -am'your message here'
$ git push
```

Comment: They indicate part of the command line is optional.  That is, you can omit the `-m'message'` bit, and git will just start an editor so you can type your message there.

Answer (score 0):

```
git init
git add folder/anotherFolder/file.php
git commit -am "your commit message"
git remote add origin <the_url_remote_repository>
git push -u origin master
```

Where `the_url_remote_repository` is something like that (example for github) :

```
git@github.com:yourprofile/thereponame.git
```